# Cypress.io: CLI --config-file & Cypress.env(), undefined

Tags: cypress

I trying to figure out how to read a config file provided by CLI parameter `--config-file`

Using this parameter as follows `cypress open --config-file cypress/config/stage.json`

Contents for `stage.json` file is:

```
{
  "auth_url": "https://example.com/",
  "auth_username": "username@example.com",
  "auth_password": "password"
}
```

However... using `Cypress.env('...')`, values return undefined, as detected by the following `expect`.

```
const authUsername = Cypress.env('auth_username');
const authPassword = Cypress.env('auth_password');
const authUrl = Cypress.env('auth_url');

expect(authUsername).to.be.a('string').not.empty;
expect(authPassword).to.be.a('string').not.empty;
expect(authUrl).to.be.a('string').not.empty;
```

What am I missing? Thank you, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to read the values from `stage.json` config file, you need to use the command `Cypress.config` instead of `Cypress.env`:

```
// Use Cypress.config
{
  "auth_url": "https://example.com/",
  "auth_username": "username@example.com",
  "auth_password": "password"
}
```

If you want to read with `Cypress.env` command, within `stage.json` you should declare as:

```
// Use Cypress.env
{
    "env": {
        "auth_url": "https://example.com/",
        "auth_username": "username@example.com",
        "auth_password": "password"
    }
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated, checking this out tonight!